# Automatic upload from C drive to web server using php

Tags: php, file-upload

I have requirement to upload photos to server using php. Usually, the user selects the image to upload using html file input and we upload the file on submit. My requirement is to avoid the file selection step. As soon the user visits my web page, a file from C:\photo.jpg has to be uploaded to server. Is it possible using php?

Comment: from client PC or your server drive??

Comment: This is called a Bad Idea (tm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible, you cannot directly access the drive from browser. It's a security issue.

Just think about what it will happen if I can gather 1 file from each visitor, let's say saved passwords from browsers?

Answer (score -1):

i think it is possible but with j query. bcoz if saw at image sliders, in many image sliders images are picked up from a special folder and showed in slider..